# Rails: Get relationship on array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I don't know if there's a good answer for this. Let's say I have:

```
users = User.where(:location => "Utopia") #=> Returns [user1,user2,user3,user4]
```

I would like do something like:

```
users.photos #=> Returns all photos this group of users has
```

And simply get all the photos back without iterating over them. I ask because each iteration is a DB call. Is there any good way that does a single DB call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to use the eager loader:

```
users = User.where(:location => 'Utopia').includes(:photos)
```

That will fetch the users in one pass, then the relationships and their associated photos in another. You can wrap it all up into one call if you either use a `JOIN` or a subselect, it's your call, but it'll look something like this:

```
photos = Photo.includes(:user).where('users.location' => 'Utopia')
```

There's more information available in the [Active Record Query Interface documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) in section 12.

Comment: Yeah, would be a little more efficient to do an inner join rather than a LOJ - `photos = Photo.joins(:user).where(:users => {:location => 'Utopia'})`

Comment: Is it possible to specify which key I want to use when performing the join? The relationship is setup through `:has_many :through` and the return uses the wrong keyset.